How many votes do you need to count to know the winner?
In the upcoming election they are not going to announce the winner till every mail in vote is counted. This could take many days and is just bad for confidence in the system.
I am thinking if they took all the mail in ballots and mixed them in a large container then we could look at a much smaller sample of ballots to say who won.
So, if we have a million ballots and we want to know within a 95% confidence level who won, how many ballots would we need to count? We will assume that one candidate has at least 1% more ballots than the other.
According to this video from Khan academy it seems like the population size does not matter, only sample size.
So we have sample size n where...  $$\sqrt\frac{ {0.51*0.49}}{n} = \frac {0.01}{2}$$
$$n = 9996$$
So, if one candidate has more then 51% of the vote after 9,996 ballots are counted then she will win at least 95% of the time, assuming that the population of ballots were thoroughly mixed.
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/xfb5d8e68:inference-categorical-proportions/introduction-confidence-intervals/v/confidence-intervals-and-margin-of-error

For questions on this site, you need to be a lot more specific.

Look up Standard Z-score for 95% is 1.96
Since there’s a minimum 1% lead, we'll set the margin of error at 0.5% (0.005) to confidently identify the winner with the assumed gap.
Sample Size Formula for Proportion:
$$n=\frac{ {Z^2*p * (1-p)}}{M^2} $$
Z = Z-score corresponding to 95% confidence (1.96)
p = assumed proportion of votes for the leading candidate (use 0.505 for a close race where the candidate has a slight lead)
M = Margin of error (0.005)
$$n=\frac{ {1.96^2*0.505 * (1-0.505)}}{0.005^2} $$
$$n=38,412 $$
To estimate the winner with a 95% confidence level, you would need to count approximately 38,412 ballots. This sample size accounts for a close race where one candidate has at least a 1% lead over the other.
This is for an infinite number of ballots, the value for a finite number of ballots would be slightly less, but who is counting.
I will be going to the county elections office today to volunteer to help count the mail in ballots. Even if my numbers are wrong, I think that it is safe to say that you can turn many skewed batches of ballots into one large homogenous batch of ballots that can be easily assessed in a short period of time without counting all the ballots. Even though all the ballots will be tabulated in due time.
